# Why do I get funny glich in my viewport?

Tags: rendering

I'm seeking for some infos about a glitch that happen in my viewport when I make volumetric clouds in eevee. I'm working on a iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013). Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 and my graphics is an Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB[image: I]

I hope someone would be able to answer me about this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.81? I've experienced the same thing, especially with volumetrics. My Amateur guess is that it's just a bug. It usually works fine again after a restart.

Comment: I just downloaded V2.81 and same thing is happening. Like you said. Espacially with volumetric.